# Wordpress get_post(); Only Returning 5 Entries

Tags: wordpress, plugins, foreach

This has been driving me nuts trying to figure out: In my plugin I have a section that pulls all entries out of the Database - we'll say all posts, but I also display Pages and Categories - using this line of code:

```
$args_posts = array(
                'numberposts'       => -1,
                'suppress_filters'  => true
);
$posts = get_pages($args_posts);
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    //formatting & display
}
```

...and then this get looped, formatted, and echoed using a foreach() statement.

**The problem I'm having is that it runs fine on my server but when I have a friend try it it only shows 5 posts**. The environment it needs to work under will end up having several thousand entries. Originally, the problem was there for me too but I didn't supply the arguments for `get_posts()` - I just set it as a variable itself using `$posts = $get_pages()`, and once I added the arguments it resolved. But my friend is still seeing only 5 entries displayed, even though there's no browser cache or server cache and other changes in the script are coming through.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wordpress Docs:

> ## Number
>
> *(integer)* Sets the number of Pages to list. This causes the SQL LIMIT value to be defined. Default to no LIMIT. This parameter was
>   added with Version 2.8. Note: get_posts() uses the parameter
>   'numberposts' instead of 'number'. Second Note: it doesn't work if
>   used together with 'child_of'. Instead use 'parent' and set
>   'hierarchical' to false.

Link:
[Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

In otherwords change `numberposts` to `number`

Comment: Thank you ; I have trouble with reading comprehension and the WP Codex can be like reading War and Peace sometimes. Number for get_posts() and numberposts for get_pages(). Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Follow-up: Any idea why it works in some environments and not others? As far as I'm aware my friend's theme isn't at issue.

Comment: You should show the relevant code change(s), so the answer has the full context for people who find this question.